# Why does multicast streaming only work with 224.0.0.0/4 routed to network card/NIC in Linux?

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player, multicast, static-routes

a project of mine involves multicast streaming of DBV-S2 TV channels by using a networked SAT tuner. As there are no IGMP-capable network switches, the network is quite stressed and so I set up a physically separate network.

This new network contains a DHCP server (Linux Mint 16 with isc-dhcp-server; network tuner doesn't support static IP), the network tuner, a Linux (Mint 16) computer and a Windows 7 laptop. The network tuner will send a RTP stream to `239.5.2.1` on port 6670 in this case.

This is my dhcpd.conf:

```
ddns-update-style interim;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.20.255;
subnet 192.168.20.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        interface eth0;
        range 192.168.20.1 192.168.20.10;
}
host tuner {
        hardware ethernet 54:84:7b:00:19:1a;
        fixed-address 192.168.20.2;
}
```

On Windows 7, VLC can open `rtp://@239.5.2.1:6670` just fine. In Linux, that doesn't work. Message log of VLC says: "Cannot join multicast group. No such device." When I add

```
sudo route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev eth0
```

it suddenly works. I found some [explanation here](http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/netsp/article.php/3623181/Networking-101--Understanding-Multicast-Routing.htm), but in the standard network VLC could play the stream without that route. What might be different in my network and the regular one? I didn't install the regular network and I don't know much about it. It also has a DHCP.

Maybe someone can shed some highly appreciated light on this.